# Yii2 - Logging 500 errors on production

Tags: php, logging, yii2

Im trying to debug an Internal Server Error on production that runs Yii2.

To do this, I added `EmailTarget` to my config file as follows

```
if(!YII_DEBUG){
    $logTarget[] = [
        'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
        'mailer' =>'mailer',
        'levels' => ['error'],
        'message' => [
            'from' => ['mail@example.com'],
            'to' => ['mymail@example.com'],
            'subject' => 'Log',
        ],
        'categories' => [
            'yii\db\*',
            'yii\web\HttpException:*',
        ],
        'except' => [
            'yii\web\HttpException:404',
            'yii\web\HttpException:403',
            'yii\web\HttpException:401'
        ]
    ];
}
```

then

```
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => 3,
        'targets' => $logTarget,
    ],
```

Im not getting the 500 errors though. Am I doing smt wrong? Or are 500 errors not logged by default

Comment: You didn't say which server you are running php on top of. If you are running on Apache2 then check `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: but I mean in the general case, yii2 can not log the 500 errors? @StefanoMtangoo

Comment: it does always log all errors for sure. but sometimes things fails at apache lever so Yii2 caanot even know about them

Comment: Ahhh okk, I see your point.
But technically in your opinion there's nothing wrong with the configuration above, right?

Comment: `$logTarget[] = [...]` should be `$logTarget = [[...]]`

Comment: `yii\web\HttpException:*` should be `yii\web\HttpException*` in categories

Comment: Same change fo except. Try changing those and if they work fine, I can write the answer fully

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo thanks a lot with the help man! :)
What fixed the problem for me at last is removing categories entirely. I think the problem here had to do with HttpException, but its presence in the first place not the way its written.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally got it working. 
Apparently, the `'categories'` here blocked 500 errors from being sent probably since most 500 errors belong to `yii\base\Excetion` and not `yii\web\HttpException`.
Since, by default, if no `'categories'` are put, all the errors are included, just removing this from the array fixed the problem.

My fixed array is:

```
if(!YII_DEBUG){
    $logTarget[] = [
        'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
        'mailer' =>'mailer',
        'levels' => ['error'],
        'message' => [
            'from' => ['mail@example.com'],
            'to' => ['mymail@example.com'],
            'subject' => 'Log',
        ],
        'except' => [
            'yii\web\HttpException:404',
            'yii\web\HttpException:403',
            'yii\web\HttpException:401'
        ]
    ];
}
```