# Logging http error codes (500, 504) in telegram chat with bot

Tags: php, nginx, yii2, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have site that working with `yii2` and `nginx`, send information from site pages to the chat in telegram with bot.

Sometimes site can't load page or have troubles with something else. The task is that bot need text to chat, `have problem HTTP:CODE`, **I don't want to solve problems with loading pages, I talk about other.**

On that moment bot can text if `HTTP` code error is `403`, BUT, this method can't work with `500`,`504` error codes (Man who have big experience in this job, say, that isn't work, because php code will not run on these errors)

I can't give source code (closed repository) I didn't write this question if Google searching give results, only HTTP errors from telegram (account that send message in blacklist)

**Thanks for help**

**UPD** found how error 403 logging in this project `https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-logging` and found same theme where text that error 500 logging in `apache` but in this project use `nginx` `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023726/yii2-logging-500-errors-on-production/55062137`